# How do I collapse a table row or grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

In this image, I need collapsing in breakfast row. Does anyone know how I can collapse whole `tr` or else with `div`?

[image: collpsingRow]

Comment: Please show us what you have done and what obstacles you are facing some code would definitely help to move your issue forward

Comment: https://codepen.io/krishna-sudo/pen/YzPaVvE?editors=1000 please follow this url

Answer (score 0):

You need some reference for locating the table. In this example table should have a class called "myTable":

```
$('.myTable tr').eq(0).hide();
```

eq(number): Number is the position of the tr. On your example there are 7 tr.

Hope this helps